# How to enter django form information into the DB

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I saw the form documentation in the django site and I wonder how to add the data to the DB.

That`s the HTML :

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
    <input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

That`s the function example given in the documentation :

```
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Now I need to see how a function the adds the name to the database will look like.

Answer (score 2):

I hope `NameForm` is a modelform. in this case just [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)ing brings the data into db.

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

if your form is a normal form, then you need to grab the passed value and create/assign to/ a model object:

```
if form.is_valid():
    # modifying
    name_object = Name.objects.get(some_field=some_field)
    name_object.name_field = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
    name_object.save()

    # or creating
    new_name_object = Name(name_field=form.cleaned_data['your_name'])
    new_name_object.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it without a form class?

For example : 

def get_name(request):
        var = Name(request.POST)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

Answer (score 0):

for example:

my own model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    var = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

so in my view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    var = form.cleaned_data['var']
    # do insertion or modification or deletion
    obj = MyModel.objects.create(var=var)
    obj.save()
```

You'd better take a look at the manual, it's detailed.

Comment: Hey,

Is it possible to do it without using a django form?

For example :                                                                  





--class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

--def add_name(request):
    var = request.POST['name']
    obj = MyModel.ojects.crate(name=var)
    obj.save()

Comment: @TomerI yes it is. django form just provides validation for you so you have no need to do that yourself. it's a convenient tool to clean the raw data.

Comment: I tried it and it does not seem to work.
Can you list eh things that must be done for it to work so I can check if I missed anything?
Thanks

Comment: There`s no report. 
It seems to work but after I sumit the data ti does not change in the DB.
Any chance to comunicate with you privately somehow?

Comment: @TomerI this is my gmail: haizhipan@gmail.com